# Overlapping Image in TableViewCell iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uiimageview, height

I am new to stackoverflow and couldn't find a solution to my problem. So I hope one of you might help. I am currently porting my app to iOS 7 and I am struggling with a design problem.

Within iOS 6 I had a tableview cell (the last one) with a height of 10px containing an image with a height of 40 px. So by scrolling down the user could see all of the image but only the top 10 px if the tableview snapped back upon releasing his finger from the touchscreen.

With iOS 7 I can't get this to work. If I set the row hight to 10 px only the top is visible and the bottom part is cut off :(

It seems as with iOS 7 the tableViewCell's content can not be larger than its height...

I hope my question is understandable. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the view hierarchy changed slightly in ios7 for table view cells.

I set the clips to bounds on the contentView's superview:

[cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];

It worked like a charm :D